# My laptop battery discharged in sleep mode?

Tags: laptop, battery, sleep, acer-aspire, battery-life

My laptop computer is an Acer Aspire M5-583P-6428 touch screen laptop computer. Its specs are as follows:

> Intel i5-4200u Quad-Core Processor
>
> Intel HD 4400 Integrated Graphics
>
> 500GB hard drive (spinning-disk)
>
> 3560 mAh 4-cell lithium polymer battery, advertised up to 6.5 hours battery life (though I have seen it do much better)
>
> 8GB DDR3 RAM (~7.66 usable)
>
> Windows 8.1 Update 1

A couple times lately, I have noticed something strange occurring.

What happens is this. My computer will be fully charged, and I'll put it into sleep mode and put it up, sometimes for a day or more at a time, because parents (though that doesn't matter at the moment).

What I've had happen twice to me now is this. When I get to school in the morning, I'll open up my computer and attempt to turn it on. The battery light will blink orange at me a couple times, and then do nothing; I'm sure this is the indication that the battery has died, but it's most likely just that it has only 5% charge remaining.

I've had my laptop since August 8, 2013, and this has only happened twice - Once this morning (December 8th at the time of writing this), and once before, some weeks ago. I'm not sure whether to think this is just a result of being in Sleep mode for days at a time, or if my computer is acting up again.

Could someone please provide me with some insight to this issue and/or assist me in reaching a solution?

**NOTE**: For those who are contemplating criticism for how I use Sleep mode, please know that I only do so because of its convenience; I usually have multiple important tabs open in Google Chrome, and also prefer to start right back where I left off in my programming projects rather than try to remember what exactly I was working on.

Comment: There is a difference between Suspend and Sleep.  One will drain the battery the other places the device in a state there isn't drain on the battery.  Sleep places the device in a state where there will be drain on the power.  You want to be using suspend instead.

Comment: I thought I had this problem; I'll record here what was actually going on in case this helps anyone else.  I was hitting Windows + L, thinking I was putting the computer to sleep.  Turns out Windows L only does Switch User.  Thus, the battery was draining because the computer was not actually asleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleep mode uses battery if not a whole lot of it. Some motherboards will also "wake" the laptop in the presence of a signal from some connected device. As an example, I have a laptop that will wake up if I have a wireless mouse dongle plugged in and don't turn off the mouse before putting it to sleep; the very act of moving the mouse signals a wake-up.

So, the best explanation is that your laptop woke up from sleep mode and drained its battery. Windows is configured by default to automatically put laptops in hibernate at a certain battery level (I believe 1%). You can verfy this by checking the event logs for events in the time you expected it to be asleep.

Edit: As an aside, use Hibernate. It's a bit slower to boot up but these wake problems will go away.

Comment: That could be the case! I might have my computer configured to wake upon receiving a signal from my home network. Also, peripherals can be singled out, as I usually unplug my mouse and store the computer in its bag before I put it away.

Comment: Yeah, network can also do it. Some wireless adapters stay live to accept Wake-On-LAN packets from the network. Using the hardware switch if you have one to turn it off will help - or of course, disable wake on lan capability.

Comment: I'm poking around in the device settings, and I noticed that I do indeed have WoLAN and WoWLAN enabled.

Comment: Alright, for now I've disabled Wake-On-LAN, which is most likely the problem. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.